# Should artifacts associated with a build record be deleted when the build record is deleted?

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am using the new VSO scriptable build system with an on premise build agent.

The build publishes the following assets to an internal file share.

1. Install
2. Symbols to our internal symbol store.

When a build is deleted either manually or based on retention policy the associated assets are *not* deleted.

Should I expect that assets are deleted when the associated build record is deleted?

Comment: I would say "it depends". You should have the choice as you do with the old XAML build system. I would expect this to be available at, or shortly after, RTM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 2015 RTM and currently in VSO, server drops are deleted when a build is deleted but drops to UNC shares are not.

We have work on our backlog to address this.

EDIT:

In 2015 QU2, this is enabled.  Also if you on-prem agents against VSTS in recent sprints it works.  It queues the job to delete the share with the same demands that the build was built with.  This likely lands on an agent running as the same account that wrote to the UNC share.  It uses the account the agent runs as to attempt to delete the share (best effort)

Comment: As a side note, there's discussions around the best way to handle.  The approach of delegating to an agent and hoping it has access to the share is problematic at best.  We're also discussion a PS cmdlet where it can list builds deleted and pipe that to something that can delete the share and you run as an identity that has access to the drops ...