# TFS 2015 Update 1 vNext Build artifacts not deleting?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are using TFS 2015 Update 1.

We can delete a build or it will roll off (based on retention policy), however, nothing from the build gets deleted.

- Symbols on symbol server
- Build artifacts
- Test Results
- Source

Is there anything that needs to be specially configured to enable this, is this a known issue?

This stackoverflow mentions it here, but mostly talks about drop locations: [Should artifacts associated with a build record be deleted when the build record is deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276466/should-artifacts-associated-with-a-build-record-be-deleted-when-the-build-record)

Microsoft's documentation says that The build record, Logs, Published artifacts, Automated test results, Published artifacts, and Published symbols. However, unsure if this is a VSTS thing as we are using TFS 2015 on premise: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/define/retention

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is a misunderstanding. I assume what you are seeing is the resources in your build workspace, not the build details. If you delete the resources in the build workspace, all build details still can be seen on web access.

Actually, when you delete a build manually, everything about build will be deleted, check the screenshot below:

[image]

If you specify build retention policies, Retention policies will delete the items below:

- The build record
- Logs
- Published artifacts
- Automated test results
- Published artifacts
- Published symbols

You can set Policy options for `Delete build record`, `Delete source label`, `Delete test results`, but you can't turn off deletion of artifacts or logs (note that, for artifacts, only server drops are deleted when a build is deleted but drops to UNC shares are not):

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.

Right it makes sense that UNC file share drops are not deleted. 

But what about the local source in AgentName\agent\_work\18\s and drop in AgentName\agent\_work\18\a\drop\bin\Debug - these still exist. Is this by intention?

Also, published symbols on a network drive location are not deleted, either.

Comment: What you are talking about is working directory for the build agent. If you want to delete the content in working directory for the build agent, you can add a task "Delete files" to delete source folder $(Agent.BuildDirectory), check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/steps/utility/delete-files

Comment: Okay, so that isn't meant to be deleted automatically, I see. That's in part what we were trying to figure out.  There is still the question of the published symbols that aren't getting deleted, though.

Comment: If the symbols have been published, they won't be deleted. It's similar to Drop type. Published symbols will be stored in UNC shares. If you don't publish the symbols, ther will be source indexed, which will be deleted.