# TFS 2015 - Delete Build Artifacts

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

How to step up TFS 2015 Update 2 to delete artifacts when build is deleted?

Is this possible?

[image]

EDIT: Add retention screen shot

I am using the default retention policy but it is NOT deleting artifacts from the drive.

[image]

EDIT: Add Copy and Publish Build Artifacts

[image]

EDIT: Add Working Folder

I added a powershell to display all environment variables and it said my workingFolder = E:TfsBuilds\Agent1_WorkPlace\5\s

Do you a powershell to set workingFolder to default?

Here is the file structure i have:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you [specify build retention policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/define/retention), retention policies will delete the items below:

- The build record
- Logs
- Published artifacts
- Automated test results
- Published artifacts
- Published symbols

More details you can refer a similar question in SO: [Should artifacts associated with a build record be deleted when the build record is deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276466/should-artifacts-associated-with-a-build-record-be-deleted-when-the-build-record)

Moreover, if you manually delete the build, everything of  the build will be deleted.

**Update**

---

For now, server drops are deleted when a build is deleted **but drops to UNC shares are not.** It's also a known issue: [Build.Preview - Drop Folder not deleted when build is deleted](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1513256/build-preview-drop-folder-not-deleted-when-build-is-deleted)

If so, you may have to **delete them manually**.

**Update2**

---

I was wondering did you missed up the working folder with the drop folder. The default work folder location is a _work folder directly under the agent installation directory. The files in this folder will always keep or deleted until next build triggered. You can find the directory in your build log to double check this. More details please refer the definition from [MSDN](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/agents/windows).

[image]

---

**Update3**

Each agent will have their own work folder. Such as XXX\Agent1, XXX\Agent2,...XXX\Agent6. I think the issue is that you are confusing the file structure.

With your file structure, the files which deployed to the server is copying to the folder called XXX\builds. However, **these files are not the published Artifacts**. There are something like temporary files. If you want to auto delete the files under the builds, you can add a [Delete files task.](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/steps/utility/delete-files)  at the last step. Even if these files are deleted during the build. You can **still download the artifacts from server after build finished.** 
[image]

Comment: I am using the default retention policy but i doesn't delete the artifact from the drive.

Comment: I also try to manually delete the build and it did NOT delete the artifacts

Comment: Are you publishing the artifacts to a UNC share folder? For now, server drops are deleted when a build is deleted but drops to UNC shares are not. It's also a known issue https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1513256/build-preview-drop-folder-not-deleted-when-build-is-deleted . If so, you may have to delete them manually.

Comment: I am dropping in the build server (actually for now i have everything on the same server - TFS, Build, Drop location)  on the secondary drive E:\tfsbuilds\builds\......

Comment: According to the screen shot this  `E:\tfsbuilds\builds  \......` is the UNC path, The UNC folder could also in the build server or some other machines which your build agent can connected to. If you choice to publish to server, you will not see the path unless you use REST API.  Could you share the screenshot of *Publish Artifacts* or *Copy and Publish Artifacts* step, if you are not sure about this ,

Comment: Added copy and Publish Artifact steps

Comment: Your step looks well . Test the same setting with my TFS, artifacts published to the server deleted successful when the build deleted. Since you have mentioned you put everything on the same server. I was wondering did you missed up the working folder with the drop folder. The default work folder location is a _work folder directly under the agent installation directory. More details please see my update.

Comment: @123456789 I don't have that powershell script  to set workingFolder to default. However, you can Run Command Prompt as Administrator on your build server, and then run: ` 
C:\Agent\ConfigureAgent.cmd ` to configure your build agent.  `/Configure`  `/WorkFolder:WorkFolder`
The default work folder location is a _work folder directly under the agent installation directory. You can change the location to be outside of the agent installation directory, for example: `/WorkFolder:C:_work`.  Note: you need to run this command at the agent installation directory.

Comment: I looked at the configuration and they look right: WorkFolder: "E:\\TfsBuilds\\Agent1_WorkPlace for agent1 and WorkFolder: "E:\\TfsBuilds\\Agent2_WorkPlace  for agent2. Do you think the issue is that each agent (I have two) have diffrent workplace?

Comment: No that's the default  setting. Each agent will have their own work folder. Such as XXX\Agent1, XXX\Agent2,...XXX\Agent6. I think the issue is that you are confusing the file structure. The files which deployed to the server is copying to the folder called XXX\builds. These files are not the published Artifacts. There are something like temporary files. If you want to auto delete the files under the builds, you can add a Delete files task. Even if these files are deleted during the build. You can still download the artifacts from server after build finished. Details please see my update answer

Comment: I think you are right... I thought that copy files to the XXX\builds were published artifacts. When i delete the build from XXX\builds, it still shows in the web portal under the artifact. But when i try to download it, it downloaded an empty zip file.When i try to extract files from the zip folder, it give me the following error "Windows cannot complete the extraction. The Compressed (Zipped) Folder 'C:\Users\username\Deaktop\artifact.zip' is invalid". Any ideas why?

Comment: You should use the environment variable `SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY` to delete the artifacts

Comment: For anyone coming across this now... The Connect site of course has been retired, but I was able to find a copy of the issue via the internet archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20161012234209/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1513256/build-preview-drop-folder-not-deleted-when-build-is-deleted. The issue was present in TFS 2015 and was reported fixed in TFS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an assumption here that we know that TFS2015 Update2 does not support this out of the box and that MS claims to have resolved this in TFS15.

I am going to paste the whole program for everyone's benefit. This code works and I am using it. I run this utility to clean the build artifactdrop location for builds that have been wiped out of TFS. The assumption we are making is that we are going to call the exe with two parameters that are folder paths:

```
DeleteBuild.exe "D:\TFSDropLocation" "D:\DumpFolderBeforeIDeleteThis"
```

where *TFSDropLocation* is where TFS is dropping the build artifacts and *DumpFolderBeforeIDeleteThis* is a folder where I collect all builds before I delete them forever. We could have deleted them right from *TFSDropLocation* but I like this additional step where we remove them to a separate location so that just in case, we happen to need them, they are their or alternately delete them from this location after one more round of verification -if that makes you comfortable.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DeleteBuild
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length!=2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct usage is: DeleteBuild.exe 'Absolute Folderpath Path to TFS drop location' 'Absolute Dump Location'");
                Console.WriteLine("for e.g. something with quotes around the paths: DeleteBuild.exe D:\\TFSDropLocation D:\\Dumplocation");
                return;
            }

            string BuildDropLocation = args[0];
            string BuildDumpLocation = args[1];
            #region TFSConnection
            string accountUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountUrl"];
            VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(accountUrl), new VssAadCredential());
            ProjectHttpClient projectClient = connection.GetClient<ProjectHttpClient>();
            TeamProject project = projectClient.GetProject(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TeamProject"]).Result;
            BuildHttpClient buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
            var builds = buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(project.Id, resultFilter: BuildResult.Succeeded).Result;
            #endregion

            //the parent directory that is the build definition name
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(BuildDropLocation);
            // list of subdirectories which are the actual buildnumber folders
            DirectoryInfo[] ParentFolders = directory.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo ParentFolder in ParentFolders)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Build Definition name: " + ParentFolder.Name + " contains the below mentioned builds");
                //list of all folders inside the build definition folder which are buildnumber folders
                DirectoryInfo[] ChildFolders = ParentFolder.GetDirectories();
                //We evaluate each build number folder one by one
                foreach (DirectoryInfo ChildFolder in ChildFolders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Evaluating folder: " + ChildFolder.Name);
                    //Create an array of builds where the definition name matches the parent foldername
                    Build[] RelevantBuilds = builds.Where(b => b.Definition.Name == ParentFolder.Name).Reverse().ToArray();
                    //set flag to false to 
                    Boolean flag = false;
                    // traverse through each build in tfs
                    foreach (Build build in RelevantBuilds)
                    {
                        {
                            //compare build number with child folder name to see if it matches
                            if (string.Compare(build.BuildNumber, ChildFolder.Name) == 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Found build existing, hence leaving here " + build.BuildNumber);
                                //this build has yet not been deleted from tfs so set flag to true and traverse to the next build
                                flag = true;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    // if after travering the builds, we did not find any build that matches the foldername, flag will be set to initial value of false and this folder will be deleted
                    if (flag == false)
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo DropLocation = new DirectoryInfo(BuildDumpLocation);
                        string intermediatPath = Path.Combine(BuildDumpLocation, ParentFolder.Name);
                        DirectoryInfo IntermediateDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(intermediatPath);
                        if (!IntermediateDirectory.Exists)
                        {
                            DropLocation.CreateSubdirectory(ParentFolder.Name);
                        }
                        string sourcePath = ChildFolder.Name;
                        string targetPath = Path.Combine(DropLocation.FullName, ParentFolder.Name, ChildFolder.Name);
                        System.IO.Directory.Move(ChildFolder.FullName, targetPath);
                        Console.WriteLine("Did not find build in TFS hence moving: " + ChildFolder.Name + " to a separate dump location.");
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("******************************************************");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end of directory" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```