# Build retention policy - maximum number of builds

Tags: tfs

We have a build definition that gets triggered between 5 and 10 times per day.

We want to keep only the last build.

How can we achieve this with the build retention policy? The policy accepts only minimum number to keep and not the maximum number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pre TFS, Xaml builds can be configured to only ever keep the last x builds (e.g. keep the last 5 builds).

[image: Xaml Build Retention Policies]

However, vNext builds change how this works, **to keep builds for x number of days, and keep a minimum of y.**

I'm afraid you need the feature like old retention policy. There had been a related user voice:

> **Bring back old style retention policies for vNext Build
>   defintions**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/8266650-bring-back-old-style-retention-policies-for-vnext

However it got completed by adding the control of build numbers. Just not have the keep latest option. Unfortunately, you  **could not** achieve this with the build retention policy

As a workaround you could try to use TFS API to do this. You could run a utility to clean the build artifact drop location for builds. Here is a sample from [*skundu's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026812/5391065) in the link.

Comment: The TFS REST API seems to be the correct way: 

I'll use a scheduled script to loop for the builds of a build definition and delete all builds except the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the complete retention policy, the minimum number to keep and the maximum number for a team project collection. You can change the policy on the Build and Release Settings on your account or the team project account:

1. VSTS: https://{your_account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_buildQueue
2. TFS 2017: https://{your_server}/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue
3. TFS 2015 Update 3:
   http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue
4. TFS 2015 RTM: http://{your_server}:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_admin/_buildQueue#_a=settings

You can find more info about this here [Build and release retention policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention)

I hope this helps you

Comment: I'm aware how to change the policy settings; It seems that's not possible to achieve this specific scenario: keep only the last build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSTS, your builds are not deleted until 3 A.M. UTC that day.

Following is taken from the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/policies/retention

> Your retention policies run every day at 3:00 A.M. UTC. There is no
>   option to change this process.

If you are looking to get only the latest build, set the minimum number to 1. The maximum number of build retained cannot be changed for a particular build. You will need to change it to 1 for team project collection . But as I mentioned earlier, it won't mean that you will always have 1 build.

Comment: There is no "maximum number of builds" setting for team project collection; it's only "maximum number of days".

Comment: yes, there is no maximum build for project collection either. It's just the maximum retention policy & default retention policy. 

So the answer to your question, what you are trying to do is not possible with current TFS build system.

Comment: I have blogged about the way we are retaining maximum number of builds in our build system. 

http://hamidshahid.blogspot.com/2017/11/tfs-2017-build-system-maintain-last-n.html

There is code in there. If you need more help, please let me know