# TFS client libraries don't return specific value

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tfs, tfs-2015

Why are some properties of the build defintions obtained through the TFS client libraries empty? For example, I want to get the retentionRules and daysToKeep properties of a certain build definition but the values returned are empty. When I enter the URL of the build defintion in the browser I get the JSON object with all the expected details.

```
public static void BuildDefinitionSample()
{
    VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(collectionUri), new VssClientCredentials());

    var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
    var buildDefinitions = buildClient.GetDefinitionsAsync(project: projectName, name: "MyBuildDefinition").Result;

    var daysToKeep = buildDefinitions.FirstOrDefault().retentionRules.daysToKeep;
}
```

How can I get the daysToKeep property of a certain build defintion through the TFS client libraries?

Thank you

Comment: Are all of the builds using the same build system? There are XAML builds and modern builds.

Comment: Some of them are XAML builds. But the build defintion in question is a modern build.

Comment: I expect that you just answered your own question: XAML builds have those properties. Modern builds don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS Client libraries (SOAP API) use [Legacy Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146(v=vs.120).aspx) while WebApi libraries calls the [New Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview) to achieve the functions.

Client libraries are primarily there to supply backward compatibility with XAML builds. They cannot work well with the new vNext build system as they were written before their time.

TFS are even using two different **Build Retention Policy** for XAML build and vNext build. You could not set "daysToKeep" for a XAML build. Details please refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092773/5391065) in this question.

[image: Xaml Build Retention Policies]

So the REST API is the future way to follow and you need use it to get above values in your question.